# Lorenz System in reference to Astrophysics / Planetary orbits

Tags: orbital-motion, simulations, planets, celestial-mechanics, chaos-theory

From my research I have found that there are a system of ordinary differential equations for atmospheric convection.

What I am seeking are any [Lorenz equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system) that apply to any areas of Astrophysics or more specifically planetary orbits.

My goal is to learn more about these equations and perform a simulation of them. But I am more interested in its application within Astrophysics.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Lorenz system of equations c[ome from a model of convection of a two-dimensional flow of fluid of uniform depth](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LorenzAttractor.html), where they represent the growth of particular wave-modes. They might apply to some convective systems, but they are very abstract.

They have nothing to do with planetary orbits.

That said, strange attractors as demonstrated by this system show up in astrophysics in [some places](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9789027721259). The most obvious is stellar dynamics, where [some variable stars have slightly similar-looking dynamics](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167278915300269). There are also dynamo currents generating planetary and stellar magnetic fields. In the case of planetary orbits chaos plays an interesting role, but since this is not a dissipative system there are no real attractors but rather [chaotic regions separated by quasiperiodic orbits](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/KAM_theory_for_the_three-body_problem).

This [book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/chaos-and-complexity-in-astrophysics/4CBE479DA5574E327415F882EC7C2AB8) may be relevant.